# Issue with std::BinaryPredicate using Solaris CC

Tags: c++, solaris, sunstudio

I have a problem on Solaris using the Sun Studio compiler. It seems related to libCstd.

Consider the following code :

```
#include <list>
static bool f(double fFreq1, double fFreq2) { return false; }
int main()
{
    std::list< double > l;
    l.unique(f);
}
```

The error message I get is :

```
"uniq.cpp", line 6: Error: Could not find a match for std::list<double>::unique(bool(double,double)) needed in main().
```

But when I use references instead of values, it compiles just fine :

```
#include <list>
static bool f(const double& fFreq1, const double& fFreq2) { return false; }
int main()
{
    std::list< double > l;
    l.unique(f);
}
```

Compilation is ok for both using g++. Does anyone know what is going on ? Thanks !

Comment: Perhaps an error in the library implementation. Can you look up the relevant part in the list header?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot find the header file.

Comment: How about something like `grep -rH searchTerm /usr/include` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try building with `-library=stlport4` as the standard C++ library is not standards compliant. See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solarisstudio/documentation/cplusplus-faq-355066.html#LibComp5 for more info.